# Register SmartChineseAnalyzer plugin into SOLR

Tags: solr, sitecore

Currently I'm using SOLR version 4.3.0 and need to add SmartChineseAnalyzer plugin into SOLR. Is there a guide available on how to configure or add this plugin into SOLR instance? I have been trying to look around, but can't find anything that is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's very easy :

1 , copy contrib\analysis-extras\lucene-libs\lucene-analyzers-smartcn-x.y.z.jar to server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib

2, add follow content in your schema.xml
[image: content]

3, restart solr and  enter solr ui , select core's analysis , test it .